# Express route share variables

Tags: node.js, express

I recently started to learn node.js + Express and found it very interesting.

I have read many postings about sharing variables in routing, and many of them were using module.exports and exports.

I decided to make a function to setup a local variable

routes/test.js

```
var db;
exports.setup = function(_db){
  db = _db;
};

exports.doit = function(req, res){
  db.get("testToken", function(err, result) { 
    console.log("err: " + err);
    console.log("result: " + result);
    res.send("respond with a resource");
  });
};
```

app.js

```
var redis = require("redis");
var db = redis.createClient();
var test = require("./routes/test.js");
test.setup(db);

// configuration...

app.get('/', test.doit);
```

Is it ok to do things like this?

I want to make sure that I don't make db connections more than once, and sharing vars was the only way I could think of...

Can you make any suggestions?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine. Though, you might consider separating "setup" from the "routes."

Since `db` is always the same value, you can use Express 3's [`prototype` objects](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-3.x) to attach it to the `req` and/or `res` objects in all routes:

`routes/test.js`

```
exports.doit = function(req, res){
  req.db.get("testToken", function(err, result) { 
    console.log("err: " + err);
    console.log("result: " + result);
    res.send("respond with a resource");
  });
};
```

`app.js`

```
var redis = require("redis");
var db = redis.createClient();
var test = require("./routes/test.js");

// "setup"
express.request.db = express.response.db = db;

// configuration

app.get('/', test.doit);
```

Though, you can also define "setup" as a custom middleware:

```
// before: app.use(app.router);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.db = res.db = db;
  next();
});
```

Comment: I think I will go with this way, since I have to use db connections with other routes as well.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it looks fine, but it might be `module.exports` instead of just `exports`?

Also I would encapsulate the module code into self executed anonymous function to prevent name conflicts and declare `module.exports` once.

Something like this:

```
(function() {
  var _db;

  setup = function (db){
    _db = db;
  };

  doit = function (req, res){
    _db.get("testToken", function(err, result) { 
      console.log("err: " + err);
      console.log("result: " + result);
      res.send("respond with a resource");
    });
  };

  module.exports = {
    setup: setup,
    doit: doit
  }
}).call(this);
```

Comment: The additional closure isn't really necessary with Node.JS: "[*Variables local to the module will be private.*](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)"

Comment: Thank you. Nice to know. As I was writing modules in CoffeeScript and it compiles them this way, I really thought it is "a must".

Comment: `exports` and `module.exports` are equivalent when you don't use both in the same file so `exports` is fine. [Link](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-exports-vs-module-exports.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comments & answer. Can I ask another quick question? I was not able to use db = db inside exports.setup. so I ended it up with using _db instead... could you tell me why?

Comment: Names of function arguments "hide" outer variables with the same name within the function, so what you were doing was simply assigning your argument to itself, not to the module-scoped `db`.